# Mostrar resultados de una relación manyToOne con usuario del lado de angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

Estoy haciendo una app en angular ya guardo y cargo correctamente todo los datos, solo uno se muestra aunque si se guarda.

Dado que queria añadir mas datos a la entidad Usuario cree otra entidad llamada Extended User, para poder guardar y actualizarlas juntas extendí User en el DTO, todo se guarda correcto menos el usuario que si lo registra pero no muestra el resultado (ahora se que era por que los objetos no coincidían) en la entidad Extended User por si sola si muestra correctamente los datos pero es porque en el DTO trae a el coordinador como un Long coordinadorId pero como yo guardo primero el usuario y luego a ExtendedUser cuando quiero hacer setCordinador en lugar de traer el set coordinador del DTO que es un long me trae el de extendedUser.java que es un objeto User user.

Es un objeto de tipo User (estoy usando Jhipster) llamado coordinador .

[image: Como se puede ver el objeto coordinador se guarda y ya viene en mi DTO]

El problema es que no se carga  en mi select los datos del usuario, anteriormente era un Long pues solo cargaba el id, sin embargo no tengo problema para seleccionar un usuario diferente.

[image: La lista de los usuarios si cargan y si puedo actualizar, lo que no carga son los valores actuales]

En realidad todo lo demás carga bien.

[image: Todos los demás campos se cargan de manera correcta]

Este el código de mi component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="sigemApp.extendedUser.coordinador" for="field_coordinador">Coordinador</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="field_coordinador" name="coordinador" [(ngModel)]="user.coordinador" >
                        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>getSelected
                        <option [ngValue]="(userOption)" *ngFor="let userOption of users">{{userOption.login}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

y así esta mi component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { JhiLanguageHelper, IUser, User, UserService } from 'app/core';

import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ExtendedUserService } from '../../entities/extended-user';
import { IArea } from 'app/shared/model/area.model';
import { AreaService } from 'app/entities/area';
import { IDesarrollo } from 'app/shared/model/desarrollo.model';
import { DesarrolloService } from 'app/entities/desarrollo';

@Component({
    selector: 'sigem-user-mgmt-update',
    templateUrl: './user-management-update.component.html'
})
export class UserMgmtUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    languages: any[];
    authorities: any[];
    isSaving: boolean;
    areas: IArea[];
    users: IUser[];
    desarrollos: IDesarrollo[];
    fechaIngresoDp: any;

    constructor(
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper,
        private extendedUserService: ExtendedUserService,
        private areaService: AreaService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private desarrolloService: DesarrolloService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.route.data.subscribe(({ user }) => {
            this.user = user.body ? user.body : user;
            console.log(this.user);
        });
        this.authorities = [];
        this.userService.authorities().subscribe(authorities => {
            this.authorities = authorities;
            console.log(this.authorities);
        });
        this.userService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
                this.users = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
        this.areaService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IArea[]>) => {
                this.areas = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
        this.desarrolloService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IDesarrollo[]>) => {
                this.desarrollos = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
        this.languageHelper.getAll().then(languages => {
            this.languages = languages;
        });
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }
    previousState() {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/user-management']);
    }

    save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.user.id !== null) {
            console.log('vamo a actualizar');
            console.log(this.user);
            this.userService.update(this.user).subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        } else {
            console.log('vamo a crear uno nuevo');
            console.log(this.user);
            this.userService.create(this.user).subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        }
    }

    private onSaveSuccess(result) {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.previousState();
    }

    private onSaveError() {
        this.isSaving = false;
    }

    trackUserById(index: number, item: IUser) {
        return item.id;
    }
    trackAreaById(index: number, item: IArea) {
        return item.id;
    }
    trackDesarrolloById(index: number, item: IDesarrollo) {
        return item.id;
    }
    getSelected(selectedVals: Array<any>, option: any) {
        if (selectedVals) {
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
                if (option.id === selectedVals[i].id) {
                    return selectedVals[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return option;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba haciendo mal las cosas, quizás primero debo aclarar lo que trataba de hacer, lo que hice fue crear una nueva entidad llamada ExtendedUser para poder añadir datos a la entidad Usuario de Jhipster las dos entidades están vinculadas por una relación OneToOne y para poder guardar los datos juntos extendí el DTO de usuario dentro del DTO de extended user.

```
  public ExtendedUserDTO(User user){
        super(user);
        this.puesto = user.getExtendedUser().getPuesto();
        this.sueldo = user.getExtendedUser().getSueldo();
        this.fechaIngreso = user.getExtendedUser().getFechaIngreso();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.usuarioId = user.getId();
        this.coordinadorLogin = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getLogin();
        this.coordinadorId = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getId();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getAreas());
        this.areas = user.getExtendedUser().getAreas();

    }
```

Así aunque son dos entidades diferentes las manejo juntas, la única complicación que tenia era para traer los datos de la relación pero lo resolví de esta manera:

Para empezar regrese a mi commit anterior y regenere mi entidad al hacerlo pude observa que en ExtendedUser.java la relación con coordinador la traía de esta forma:
**extendedUser.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("")
private User coordinador;

public User getCoordinador() {
    return coordinador;
}

public ExtendedUser coordinador(User user) {
    this.coordinador = user;
    return this;
}

public void setCoordinador(User user) {
    this.coordinador = user;
}
```

Cómo se puede notar el coordinador es un usuario y lo trae como un objeto de tipo usuario y mi error al inicio fue querer traer en el dto al usuario cómo eso, cuando lo mejor era traer solo su Id y su login pues en Jhipster los usuarios se buscan mediante el login en el userService.

Así que en el DTO el usuario coordinador de mi relación esta de esta manera;
**extendedUserDTO.java**

```
   private Long coordinadorId;

   private String coordinadorLogin;

   public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public String getCoordinadorLogin() {
        return coordinadorLogin;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.coordinadorLogin = userLogin;
    }
```

Ahora del lado de angular en el component.ts se crea un lista de usuarios esta si un objeto y allí trae todos los datos ya sea el id o el login, puedes compararlo con cualquier de los dos, pero yo recomiendo con el login para que al momento de enviar los datos al userResourse puedas buscar el usuario por el login y así setear correctamente.

Asi que en el component.html queda de esta manera:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="sigemApp.extendedUser.coordinador" for="field_coordinador">Coordinador</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="field_coordinador" name="coordinador" [(ngModel)]="user.coordinadorLogin" >
                        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                        <option [ngValue]="userOption.login" *ngFor="let userOption of users; trackBy: trackUserById">{{userOption.login}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Y en el componet.ts de esta otra:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { JhiLanguageHelper, IUser, User, UserService } from 'app/core';

import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ExtendedUserService } from '../../entities/extended-user';
import { IArea } from 'app/shared/model/area.model';
import { AreaService } from 'app/entities/area';
import { IDesarrollo } from 'app/shared/model/desarrollo.model';
import { DesarrolloService } from 'app/entities/desarrollo';

@Component({
    selector: 'sigem-user-mgmt-update',
    templateUrl: './user-management-update.component.html'
})
export class UserMgmtUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    languages: any[];
    authorities: any[];
    isSaving: boolean;
    areas: IArea[];
    desarrollos: IDesarrollo[];
    users: IUser[];
    fechaIngresoDp: any;

    constructor(
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper,
        private extendedUserService: ExtendedUserService,
        private areaService: AreaService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private desarrolloService: DesarrolloService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.route.data.subscribe(({ user }) => {
            this.user = user.body ? user.body : user;
            console.log(this.user);
        });
        this.authorities = [];
        this.userService.authorities().subscribe(authorities => {
            this.authorities = authorities;
            console.log(this.authorities);
        });
        this.userService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
                this.users = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
        this.areaService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IArea[]>) => {
                this.areas = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
        this.languageHelper.getAll().then(languages => {
            this.languages = languages;
        });
        this.desarrolloService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IDesarrollo[]>) => {
                this.desarrollos = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }
    previousState() {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/user-management']);
    }

    save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.user.id !== null) {
            console.log('vamo a actualizar');
            console.log(this.user);
            this.userService.update(this.user).subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        } else {
            console.log('vamo a crear uno nuevo');
            this.userService.create(this.user).subscribe(response => this.onSaveSuccess(response), () => this.onSaveError());
        }
    }

    trackUserById(index: number, item: IUser) {
        return item.id;
    }

    trackAreaById(index: number, item: IArea) {
        return item.id;
    }

    trackDesarrolloById(index: number, item: IDesarrollo) {
        return item.id;
    }

    getSelected(selectedVals: Array<any>, option: any) {
        if (selectedVals) {
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
                if (option.id === selectedVals[i].id) {
                    return selectedVals[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return option;
    }

    private onSaveSuccess(result) {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.previousState();
    }

    private onSaveError() {
        this.isSaving = false;
    }
}
```

Finalmente para guardar a el coordinador aproveche el userService usando findByLogin

```
 /**
     * PUT /users-and-extendedUser : Updates an existing User and extendedUser.
     *
     * @param extendedUserDTO the user to update
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the updated user
     * @throws EmailAlreadyUsedException 400 (Bad Request) if the email is already in use
     * @throws LoginAlreadyUsedException 400 (Bad Request) if the login is already in use
     */
    @PutMapping("/users-and-extendedUser")
    @Timed
    @Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody ExtendedUserDTO extendedUserDTO) {

         Optional<User> existingUser = userRepository.findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(extendedUserDTO.getEmail());
        if (existingUser.isPresent() && (!existingUser.get().getId().equals(extendedUserDTO.getId()))) {
            log.debug("error nombre traido : {}", extendedUserDTO.getUsuarioId());
            throw new EmailAlreadyUsedException();
        }
        existingUser = userRepository.findOneByLogin(extendedUserDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase());
        if (existingUser.isPresent() && (!existingUser.get().getId().equals(extendedUserDTO.getId()))) {
            log.debug("error nombre traido : {}", extendedUserDTO.getUsuarioId());
            throw new LoginAlreadyUsedException();
        }

        Optional<User> coordinador = userRepository.findOneByLogin(extendedUserDTO.getCoordinadorLogin());

        Optional<UserDTO> updatedUser = userService.updateUser(extendedUserDTO);
        ExtendedUser updateExtendedUser = existingUser.get().getExtendedUser();
        updateExtendedUser.setPuesto(extendedUserDTO.getPuesto());
        updateExtendedUser.setSueldo(extendedUserDTO.getSueldo());
        updateExtendedUser.setFechaIngreso(extendedUserDTO.getFechaIngreso());
        updateExtendedUser.setAreas(extendedUserDTO.getAreas());
        updateExtendedUser.setDesarrollos(extendedUserDTO.getDesarrollos());
        updateExtendedUser.setCoordinador(coordinador.get());
        extendedUserService.save(updateExtendedUser);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(updatedUser,
            HeaderUtil.createAlert("userManagement.updated", extendedUserDTO.getLogin()));
    }
```

De esta manera ya esta funcionado de manera correcta y puedo guardar y actualizar mis dos entidades al mismo tiempo, cualquier sugerencia para mejorar o simplificar la implementación es bienvenida.